# What does mkdir -p create as the parent directory or way to see its effect?

Tags: windows, command-line

I read from http://www.techonthenet.com/unix/basic/mkdir.php that the `mkdir` command "creates a single directories or multiple directories." and with option `-p` "If the parent directories don't exist, this command creates them".

I tried this command in cmd (window operating system) and saw that with `-p` and without `-p`, the command just created a file with a file name.

How do you see the effect of "If parent directories don't exist creates them." I am assuming C:\Users\chris> is the parent directory when i run the command (therefore the parent directory exists). Is there a way of seeing the effect of `-p`?

Comment: Why are you assuming that the mkdir from Unix is the same (or has the same parameters) as the one from Windows?

Answer (score 3):

The Windows shell (cmd) mkdir command does not support the mkdir syntax of Unix shells.

So on Windows, the -p just creates a directory of that name (+ whatever other directories you ask for).

And cmd's mkdir creates parent directories if they are missing anyway - i.e same behaviour as the Unix command with -p.

Comment: Windows `mkdir` only creates any intermediate directories in the path (if needed) if Command Extensions are enabled. See output from `mkdir /?`

Comment: it's not the same.. `mkdir` has errorlevel 1 on Windows if the directory exists, `mkdir -p` succeeds on nix.

Answer (score 2):

#### Is there a way of seeing the effect of `-p`?

Windows `mkdir` (or `md`) is not the same as Unix or Linux `mkdir`.

Windows `mkdir` has no `-p` option. Se below for complete details on how to use Windows `mkdir`.

> **Syntax**
>
> MD [drive:]path
>
> **Key**
>
> The path can consist of any valid characters up to the maximum
>   path length available
>
> You should avoid using the following characters in folder names - they
>   are known to cause problems
>
> © ® " - & ' ^ ( ) and @
>
> also many extended characters may not be recognised by older 16 bit
>   windows applications.
>
> The maximum length of a full pathname (folders and filename) under
>   NTFS or FAT is 260 characters.
>
> Folder names are not case sensitive, but only folder names longer than
>   8 characters will always retain their case, as typed.
>
> **Examples**

```
    C:\temp> MD MyFolder
```

> Make several folders with one command

```
    C:\temp> MD Alpha Beta Gamma
```

> will create

```
    C:\temp\Alpha\ C:\temp\Beta\ C:\temp\Gamma\
```

> Make an entire path MD creates any intermediate directories in the
>   path, if needed (if Command Extensions are enabled)
>
> For example, assuming \utils does not exist then:

```
    MD \utils\downloads\Editor
```

> is the same as:

```
    md \utils     
    cd \utils     
    md downloads     
    cd downloads     
    md Editor
```

> for long filenames include quotes

```
    MD "\utils\downloads\Super New Editor"
```

> You cannot create a folder with the same name as any of the following
>   devices: CON, PRN, LPT1, LPT2 ..LPT9, COM1, COM2 ..COM9 This
>   limitation ensures that redirection to these devices will always work.
>
> If you plan to copy data onto CDROM avoid folder trees more than 8
>   folders deep.
>
> `MKDIR` is a synonym for `MD`

Source [md](http://ss64.com/nt/md.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [md](http://ss64.com/nt/md.html) - Make Directory - Creates a new folder.